# How to convert Linq.IEnumerable(Of String) to formatted Strings

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.5

I have a `List(Of String)` that stores validation errors.  Should that list contain any items, I'd like to concatenate them into an HTML list to show each error.  Currently this is easily done like so:

```
Dim l As List(Of String) = GetErrors()
If l.Count > 0 Then
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.Append("<div><ul>")
    For Each s As String In l
        sb.Append(String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", s))
    Next
    sb.Append("</ul></div>")
    ltl_status.Text = sb.ToString()
End If
```

However, because this is quite lengthy, I wondered whether Linq could provide a shortcut.  I tried this (line breaks added for clarity):

```
If l.Count > 0 Then
    ltl_status.Text = String.Format("<div class=""failure""><ul>{0}</ul></div>", 
        (
        From s As String In l Select 
            String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", s)
        )
)
End If
```

However, given that IEnumerable is a collection, the end result is just this output in the Literal:

```
    System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.String]
```

The aim here is to build the list using the least possible lines of code.  I see that `String.Join` accepts an IEnumerable parameter, but that simply joins the items together, whereas here I need to add additional strings to the beginning and end of each item.  Is it possible?

### Answer

Based on Jon Skeet's excellent suggestions, the extension method has saved me a **ton** of time and effort:

```
Public Module CollectionSignatureMethods

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Takes each String value in a String collection, reformats using a format, and then returns all as a single String.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="ie">An IEnumerable(Of String) collection of string values</param>
    ''' <param name="formatString">The string format (as per String.Format)</param>
    ''' <returns>All of the Strings from the collection, reformatted and combined to a single String</returns>
    ''' <remarks>Jon Skeet is the daddy(!)</remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function JoinFormat(ie As IEnumerable(Of String), formatString As String) As String
        Return String.Join(String.Empty, ie.Select(Function(s As String) String.Format(formatString, s)))
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a combination of `Join` and `Select`:

```
String.Join("", _
  l.Select(Function(s as String) String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", s))
```

Of course, you could always write your own `JoinFormat` extension method - that wouldn't be hard to do, and would be potentially useful all over the place. For example, you might then have:

```
ltl_status.Text = String.Format("<div class=""failure""><ul>{0}</ul></div>",
    l.JoinFormat("<li>{0}</li>"));
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Which class would you advise adding the extension method to?  List(of String) is perhaps too far *up* the hierarchy as other types such as IEnumerable might also benefit from it

Comment: @EvilDr: I'd have thought `IEnumerable(Of String)` personally. Or even `IEnumerable(Of T)` if you're happy to just take the default formatting for any value.

Comment: I've updated the question in the hope that it can help other people in the future.